# Have items fixed in the center but enable scroll

Tags: php, html, css

I am writing a website for my Uncle's business. I just started today.

```
**Update: I have fixed the website as I got an answer.
But to all who want to know, what I was dealing with, 
I put a code snippet below. Win-Win for all.**
```

I am stuck at one thing.
First have a look here : [MyWebsiteIsHere](http://superexpress.uk.tn/www/)

Have a look at my code, its pretty primitive:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <?php include 'php/start.php'; ?>
 <?php include 'php/start2.php'; ?>
 <?php include 'php/start3.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**php/start.php**

```
<?php
  echo '<head><title>Super Express Logistics</title></head>';
  echo "<header style=\"background-color:pink\">
  <p class=\"centered\">Hello</p></header>";
?>
```

**php/start2.php**

```
<?php
  echo "<header style=\"background-color:brown\"><p class=\"centered\">Ola!
  </p></header>";
?>
```

**php/start3.php**

```
<?php
  echo "<header style=\"background-color:lightblue\">
  <p class=\"centered\">こんにちわ　！</p></header>";
?>
```

**css/stylesheet.css**

```
header{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
}

.centered {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

**The Question**
As you see in my website (kinda), when you scroll, there is some weird text overlapping in the middle. All the three texts are enclosed in `<p> SomeTextHere </p>`

I put `position:fixed` in the `css` only to put the text in the perfect center, but because of that, ALL of those texts jump to the center

Can I like, fix the position for each text in the center of their parent and when I scroll, it scrolls with the parent ?

```css
header{
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
color:white;
}

.centered{
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header style="background-color:pink"><p class="centered"> Hi !</p></header>    
    <header style="background-color:brown;"><p class="centered"> Ola !</p></header>
    <header style="background-color:teal"><p class="centered"> こんにちわ !</p></header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes.   add `position: relative;' for header and  position: absolute; for `centered`.like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/jv8xtaz9/1/

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Plz add this answer, so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Opium, when asking questions you should create a [mcve] here, in the question, using the snippet button (`<>`). This way your question will remain relevant and helpful for others even after it has been fixed on your website.

Comment: I did it ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the CSS in the below way:

```
header{
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
color:white;
}

.centered{
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```